# Why does "service networking stop" cause the screen to become blank?

Tags: networking

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 and applied all the upgrades. When I run the following command:

```
sudo service networking stop
```

The screen turns blank. This happens both on physical hardware and on VirtualBox.

Why is it happening and how do I resolve the issue?